# Combine two rows in R

Tags: r

I would like to combine two rows based on individual names in column 1.
The original file looks like this:

```
animal pnt step segments  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10   
337   1    3      660   1   1   1   1  65   1   
337   2    3      660 220 118 223 182 217 205   
420   1    3      660  41  35  71  11  13  36  
420   2    3      660   2  31  19  46   2   2  
339   1    3      660   1   1   1   3  65   1  
339   2    3      660   3   3   3  50   3   3  
341   1    3      660   4   4   4   4   4   4  
341   2    3      660  15  85  62  77  89  71  
347   1    3      660  90  62  56  12  14  15  
347   2    3      660  58 338 190  55  60 170
```

And the idea is to have something like:

```
animal V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13   
337 1 220 1 118 1 223 1 182 65 217 1 205   
420 41 2 35 31 71 19 11 46 13 2 36 2    
339 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 50 65 3 1 3    
341 4 15 4 85 4 62 4 77 4 89 4 71   
347 90 58 62 338 56 190 12 55 14 60 15 170
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Could try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df[-(2:4)])[, as.list(unlist(.SD)), by = animal]` maybe

Comment: Looks like is working fine with your code. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
aggregate(df[,-(1:4)], list(animal=df[,1]), unlist)
#   animal V5.1 V5.2 V6.1 V6.2 V7.1 V7.2 V8.1 V8.2 V9.1 V9.2 V10.1 V10.2
# 1    337    1  220    1  118    1  223    1  182   65  217     1   205
# 2    339    1    3    1    3    1    3    3   50   65    3     1     3
# 3    341    4   15    4   85    4   62    4   77    4   89     4    71
# 4    347   90   58   62  338   56  190   12   55   14   60    15   170
# 5    420   41    2   35   31   71   19   11   46   13    2    36     2
```

Comment: When I printed using `out[1:10,1:10]` looks well, but using `view(out)` doesn't.  
After this first step, my plan is to do: `table(melt(out, id.var="animal")[-2])` , and it's not working. 
Any guess?

Comment: Hm true, if often forget that `aggregate` behaves strangly when returning more than one value. In your case, I'd do `with(stack(lapply(split(df[,-(1:4)], df[,1]), unlist)), table(ind, values))`.